I can't make changes in WordPress due to disk space limits and lack of FTP access
I am facing two issues related to a WordPress website hosted on SiteGround that I need to resolve:
1 Disk Space Limit Exceeded:
My client has reached the disk space limit on their SiteGround account. When attempting to access Site Tools to manage the site, I receive the following error message:
"Site limit exceeded
You have exceeded your quota, and access to Site Tools for californiasilkplants.com is disabled. Your current usage is 128.76% of disk space quota and 34.14% of inode quota."
Because of this, I cannot access the file manager to delete unnecessary files. What steps should I take to free up space and regain access to Site Tools? Are there other ways to access the server to manage the files?
2 Lack of FTP Access in WordPress:
I need to make some changes to the WordPress site, but when I try to make modifications, it asks for FTP access. However, the client does not have any FTP users created.
I have read that it is possible to configure FTP access in the wp-config.php file. However, since Site Tools access is disabled, I cannot directly edit this file.
How can I modify the wp-config.php file to set up FTP credentials without access to Site Tools? Are there other ways to configure FTP access if I do not have direct access to the server?
Additional Information:
-The site is hosted on SiteGround.
-File and folder permissions seem correct (755 for folders and 644 for files).
-Are there any other options for freeing up space on the server or configuring FTP access that do not require access to Site Tools?
I appreciate any help or advice on resolving these issues.
What I Tried:
I attempted to access SiteGround's Site Tools to manage disk space but received an error message indicating that the space limit has been exceeded and access is disabled.
I tried connecting to the server via FTP to delete unnecessary files and free up space, but I do not have the FTP credentials as the client has not created them.
I tried to set up FTP credentials in the wp-config.php file to make changes in WordPress, but I do not have access to the wp-config.php file due to the space limit preventing access to Site Tools.
What I Expected:
To be able to access Site Tools to manage disk space and delete unnecessary files.
To be able to connect to the server via FTP to delete files and free up space.
To be able to modify the wp-config.php file to configure FTP access and make changes in WordPress.
What Actually Resulted:
I was unable to access Site Tools due to the disk space limit.
I was unable to connect to the server via FTP due to the lack of credentials.
I was unable to modify the wp-config.php file to configure FTP access due to the lack of access to Site Tools.

contact the hoster to ask how to recover space. I have seen on the website that they have a way of contacting them as a new customer which don't have an account.

If you are able to login in wordpress backend:

See for any old backups which can be deleted, that will free the disk space.
Also you should check the plugins section which are not in use or deactivated, deleting those will also reduce the disk space.
Another option, you can check the media section, and sort the images by size and look for large size image, you can delete those images after downloading them, once you are able to access the site tools and FTP, you can again upload them. Make note where those images are added up.
Also, if you are able to install the plugin, install the File manager plugin and access the files through it and check for any zip files or old backups which can be deleted.

NOTE: Make sure to download any files which are going to delete.
And if you are not able to login into wordpress backend, then only option is to contact the siteground support and ask them to remove the temp files, cache files or if you have budget to upgrade the hosting plan.
